# UFW is not blocking outgoing ipv6 pings

Tags: ufw

I'm trying to set up UFW to block outgoing connections, except on a specific interface, and also except for a specific IP. Everything seems to be working as expected, except I can still send pings to IPV6 addresses - I want those to be blocked. I don't see any conflicting rules, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if it's a bug, or if this is expected.

I disconnect my tun0 interface, and see successfully blocked IPV4 ping:

```
$ ping 192.30.255.113 # github.com
PING 192.30.255.113 (192.30.255.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

I tried an IPV6 address, but it's not getting blocked:

```
ping 2001:41d0:701:1100::29c8 # ipv6-test.com
PING 2001:41d0:701:1100::29c8(2001:41d0:701:1100::29c8) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:41d0:701:1100::29c8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=181 ms
64 bytes from 2001:41d0:701:1100::29c8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=181 ms
```

Here is my UFW config:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         LIMIT IN    Anywhere
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    LIMIT IN    Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0
1.2.3.4 1234               ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

Why is that?

Comment: R u absolutely sure tun0 is down? What does `sudo iptables-save` return?

Comment: Ooops, sorry I actually needed `ip6tables-save`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm an idiot and originally posted the output while I still had ufw disabled so I can get online to post this... my issue is still the same, here is the corrected output  https://pastebin.com/raw/z8U5PqfF

Answer (score 1):

All your IPv6 policies according to your `ip6tables-save` output are `ACCEPT`. Also you don't have any actual enabled IPv6 rules aside from predefined `ufw` tables which do nothing.

Please make sure `/etc/default/ufw` contains `IPV6=yes` and run `sudo ufw reload`.

---

I've followed your bug report and there's no bug. Default ufw IPv6 policy contains a rule which allows to ping any host on the net (icmp6 type 128).

From docs:

> When you turn UFW on, it uses a default set of rules (profile) that should be fine for the average home user. That's at least the goal of the Ubuntu developers. In short, all 'incoming' is being denied, with **some exceptions** to make things easier for home users.

Perhaps you'll need to edit some files in order to disable these rules or add a `DROP/REJECT` target as the first rule for incoming/outgoing chains:

Please check:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall#Advanced_Functionality

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Working_with_numbered_rules

Comment: My ufw file already contained that, here's the full file, as well as sysctl.conf. I've also reloaded and rebooted with the same behavior https://pastebin.com/SSSrb8j6

Comment: My conf the same as upstream source https://git.launchpad.net/ufw/tree/conf
I believe 'sudo ufw default deny outgoing' should be blocking these pings. Or at least I can't see why they shouldn't be blocked.

Comment: File a bug report against ufw. You have zero iptables ipv6 rules enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I had ufw temporarily disabled and didn't think to record the iptables output before doing so...posted the new link as a comment above

Comment: I've followed your bug report and there's no bug. Default ufw IPv6 policy contrains a rule which allows to ping any host on the net (icmp6 type 128).

Comment: sounds like a bug to me in the sense that its unexpected behavior. I don't see why IPV4 ping should be blocked but not IPV6. I will look into disabling type 128 rule today, thanks for the info

Comment: also I wouldn't considered what i'm doing as default ufw policy (out of the box defaults) because I didn't just turn ufw on, I turned ufw on AND set outgoing connections to reject. If I simply enabled ufw and got this behavior, I would agree this is and should be by-design behavior.

Comment: Let's see what developers have to say.